# Need MySQL locking expertise

Tags: mysql, locking, queue, blocking

I would like to use a MySQL table as a queue, and I would like to use it concurrently with several consumers.  I do not want any two consumers to get the same entries from it.

I originally thought something like:

```
select * 
from queue_table 
order by entry_time desc 
limit n for update;
```

Would get me the next n entries and lock them so that other consumers could not get them.
The problem is that locks are placed on the table and index entries so that when other consumers run the same query they block until the first consumer finishes their transaction.
I do not want each consumer to wait on the others to finish.  I need something like:

```
select * 
from queue_table 
where *not already locked* 
order by entry_time desc 
limit n for update;
```

so that I can get the next n unlocked records and be on my way.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible in your design to add a field in this table?

If yes a field called "locked_by" default null will do the trick
I am assuming that you remove entries from your queue table when job is done
If you have a uniq CustId

```
UPDATE queue_table 
SET locked_by = CustId
WHERE locked_by is NULL
order by entry_time desc 
limit n;
```

Then

```
SELECT * FROM queue_table 
where locked_by = "CustId"
order by entry_time
```

If you don't have a uniq custumer id you can do this

```
set @tempId :=  UUID(); ; --This wil generate a 36char uniq string
```

thein instead of CustId use @tempId as lock value

Comment: I like it.  My only concern is unlocking those records if something goes wrong with the consuming program when it processes them.  Especially if the consuming program dies for some reason and cannot unlock them by itself.  Then they are locked, but unprocessed and nothing is around to make them available again.  Perhaps setting a locked_at along with locked_by and any records that have been in a locked state for X amount of time are also fair game?